# UITableVIew swipe trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt not working

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

New iOS 11 `UITableView` Swipe action not getting called. The `delegate` and `datasource` are working fine for the table.

I am not able to swipe and see the menu items.

Below is my code for the same.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Leading & .normal") { (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
        print("Leading Action style .normal")
    }
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

    return swipeActions
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .destructive, title: "Trailing & .destructive") { (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
        print("Trailing Action style .destructive")
    }
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

    return swipeActions
}
```

I tried to call  below and its working fine.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, commit editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if editingStyle == .delete {

    }
}
```

Any hint in right direction is highly appreciated.

Comment: whats your iOS version

Comment: min. version support is iOS 11

Comment: Did you solve the problem?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to pass `true` to `UIContextualAction` in the closure `boolValue(true)`. Otherwise the handler won't allow the action.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, leadingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UISwipeActionsConfiguration? {
    let contextItem = UIContextualAction(style: .normal, title: "Leading & .normal") { (contextualAction, view, boolValue) in
        boolValue(true) // pass true if you want the handler to allow the action
        print("Leading Action style .normal")
    }
    let swipeActions = UISwipeActionsConfiguration(actions: [contextItem])

    return swipeActions
}
```

Comment: I am not able to swipe and see the menu items

Comment: By "menu items" do you mean actions?

Comment: yes , basically I am not able to swipe the UitableViewCell

Comment: Are you sure you've set the delegate? Does `didSelectRowAt` work for you?

Comment: Yes, I check didSelectRowAt is getting called

Comment: Do you have any other gesture recognizers on top of your tableview? i don't see a problem in the code. Works for me when I copy/paste.

Comment: One more thing you could check is if the `tableView.isEditing` is `true` or `false`. Needs to be `false` in order for the `trailingSwipeActionsConfigurationForRowAt` to be called.

Comment: Good to know. :)

Comment: @AuRis, so if we set `isEditing` of table to `false` then we can't implement re-ordering functionality of cells - is there a way to implement both at once? by both I meant, swipe to delete and cell re-ordering.

Answer (score 2):

For those who uses `UITableViewDiffableDataSource` you need to subclass it and `override` its `canEditRowAt` method.

```
public override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> Bool {
    true
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Code looks good, but you are missing probably missing the following the "UITableViewDelegate" in the Class declaration and also the "TableView.delegate = self" in the viewdidload() section. So it should look like:

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

   override func viewDidLoad() {
      super.viewDidLoad()
      tableView.dataSource = self
      tableView.delegate = self
   }

}
```